# how this string could be true?

Tags: java

in Java string means a collection of characters.is it true because if it is then how can we print "1" because. ("") this is used for string and I am using numeric values in a string. it compiles and executes why. as far as my teacher told me string is a collection of character I think that means more than a single word or numeric value. but "1" is single value, but still working as

Comment: A collection can hold a single value, or it can hold no values. Otherwise, I'm not really fully understanding just what it is that you're asking.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking. Please demonstrate the problem with a code sample rather than a big vague description.

Comment: A string is an array of characters.

Comment: If you have a bag of cookies, can it hold a single cookie? Or zero cookies? Bag doesn't disappear if there are no cookies or just a single cookie. String is not cookies, string is the bag.

Comment: sorry for my bad english . i know  i was unable to ask  you guys the question clearly. but i need to thank suseika to understand my weird question and able to to explain me with the way that i can understand by this example it was clear for me to understand thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hovercraft Full Of Eels says, a collection can have any number of elements, including one or zero (wich make it empty).

Also, please note that a character can be any character from your alphabet or other alphabets, numbers, symbols, etc. (I think this is limited by the underlying charset java uses).

So, a String can be

```
""

"."

"qwerty1234567"

"a"
```

etc.

Comment: thank you Hovercraft Full Of Eels . now i undertand it completely

Comment: @Pranav Joshi Please consider rephrase your question and its title as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, please upvote the comments that were helpful for you, and, if this response solve your problem, please mark it as correct.

Comment: i cant upvote now bcoz my reputation need 15 sir so sorry and u said mark it correct. but how  can you plzz tell me how to mark correct

Comment: @Pranav Joshi At the left of the beginning of the proposed answers are a check/ok symbol (not sure of how it is called). That is for marking an answer as correct. Also, It would be polite to come back when you have enough reputation for upvote comments

Comment: ok  chomsky now i get it